# Split JSON to insert in a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ssjs

I am having a problem working with ssjs in marketing cloud. I have an array with a json that corresponds to the information about the data of data extension fields, and this information in json I need to put it in a field in a data extension to later show it with ampscript. The problem is that the character limit of a data extension field is 4000, and this json has 16000 characters, so dividing 16000/4000 would require 4 fields in the data extension and then concatenate them to get them out by ampscript. How could I split the json and put every 4000 characters in a different data extension field?
[image]

thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need to split your JSON. The trick is to create your target Data Extension in Email Studio, rather than in Contact Builder, and when you define the field that should hold the JSON data, leave the field length blank - that way you will you will omit any character limits for this field in your DE.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But, unfortunately it does't work for me :(
When i put the field "Fields" in my object cols = ["...", "...", "Fields"] automatically my code stops working, and I don't know why...